# Get all records that contain a number

Tags: sql, sql-server

It is possible to write a query get all that record from a table where a certain field contains a numeric value?

something like "select street from tbladdress where street like '%0%' or street like '%1%' ect ect"

only then with one function?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this

```
declare @t table(street varchar(50))
insert into @t 
    select 'this address is 45/5, Some Road' union all
    select 'this address is only text'

select street from @t
where street like '%[0-9]%'
```

**street**

```
this address is 45/5, Some Road
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, but it will be inefficient, and probably slow, with a wildcard on the leading edge of the pattern

```
LIKE '%[0-9]%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Searching for text within a column is horrendously inefficient and does not scale well (per-row functions, as a rule, all have this problem).

What you should be doing is trading disk space (which is cheap) for performance (which is *never* cheap) by creating a new column, `hasNumerics` for example, adding an index to it, then using an insert/update trigger to set it based on the data going into the real column.

This means the calculation is done *only* when the row is created or modified, not *every single time* you extract the data. Databases are almost *always* read far more often than they're written and using this solution allows you to amortize the cost of the calculation over many `select` statement executions.

Then, when you want your data, just use:

```
select * from mytable where hasNumerics = 1; -- or true or ...
```

and watch it leave a regular expression query or `like '%...%'` monstrosity in its dust.

Comment: We use the query ones to make an export of the rows, and then put them back in with "street" and housenumber in a separate column, but thanks for they advice

Comment: If this is not a one-off search, yes this is probably a good idea. But, of course, you should use a persisted computed column rather than a trigger.

Comment: Not all DBMS' have computed columns and I believe IBM actually has a patent on that feature anyway.

Answer (score 1):

To fetch rows that contain only numbers,use this query

```
select street 
from tbladdress 
where upper(street) = lower(street)
```

Works in oracle .

Comment: This specifically gets rows/columns that only contain non-word-characters (punctuation, whitespace, etc) - but this is usually good enough.  It certainly solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution " select street from tbladresse with(nolock) where patindex('%[0-9]%',street) = 1"

it took me 2 mins to search 3 million on an unindexed field

Comment: But it will not work for the cases I produced e.g. 'this address is 45/5, Some Road'

Comment: @pewned: true but all he has to do is change = 1 to > 0. I like your solution better though.

Comment: For the record, no index in the world would help you with this query.

Comment: (at least no index supplied by any SQL database).